# UIImage in UIView and display image parts out of bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimage

I have an image in a subview that is bigger than the subview it self, is it possible to display parts of the image that are out of the subview! have tried the

```
view.clipsToBounds=NO;
```

but no lack still.

here is part of my code so far.

```
xRayView = [[XRayView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake((1024 - 800) / 2, self.device.frame.origin.y - 26, 800,530)];
        xRayView.clipsToBounds=NO;
        [xRayView setForgroundImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"xray_foreground_01" ofType: @"png"]]];
        [xRayView setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"xray_background_01" ofType: @"png"]]];
```

the foreground and the background images are bigger than the xray view

in XrayView i have 2 properties

backgroundImage
foregroundImage

and that method

```
- (void)drawRect: (CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect: rect];

    CGRect forgroundClips[] = {
        CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - self.forgroundImage.size.width)/2, 0, self.forgroundImage.size.width, currentPan.origin.y),
        CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - self.forgroundImage.size.width)/2, currentPan.origin.y + currentPan.size.height, self.forgroundImage.size.width, self.forgroundImage.size.height - (currentPan.origin.y + currentPan.size.height))
    };

    CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1, -1);
    CGContextClipToRects(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), forgroundClips, sizeof(forgroundClips) / sizeof(forgroundClips[0]));
    //CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height), self.forgroundImage.CGImage);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - self.forgroundImage.size.width)/2, 0, self.forgroundImage.size.width, self.forgroundImage.size.height), self.forgroundImage.CGImage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1, -1);
    CGContextClipToRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPan);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 153, 153, 153, 0.5);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 3);
    CGContextStrokeRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPan);
    //CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height), self.backgroundImage.CGImage);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - self.backgroundImage.size.width)/2 , 0, self.backgroundImage.size.width, self.backgroundImage.size.height), self.backgroundImage.CGImage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    // Draw a yellow hollow rectangle

   // CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
}
```

Comment: Try setting the `clipToBounds` property for the `UIImageView` objects that holds your `forgroundImage` [SIC] and `backgroundImage`. If that doesn't do it, you might need to provide us more detail about the view heirarchy of `XRayView`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A view can't draw outside of its bounds no matter what. Setting `clipsToBounds` will only allow subviews to be rendered outside of the view, but it doesn't change the fact that drawing  (in the `drawRect` method) outside of the view is not possible.

If you have access to the `XRayView` sources, see how the images are rendered. They're probably drawn in the `drawRect` method of `XRayView`. You have to add a [`UIImageView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

`clipsToBounds` means that the image will be clipped outside of the bounds. Make sure it is set to `NO`. (this was posted when the original post said `clipsToBounds = YES;`)

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad it's set to NO and still have the problem!

Comment: I think it may be because you are using these background images, go into xRayView and make sure backgroundImage(view) and foregroundImage(view) are set to `clipsToBounds=NO`